# How to assign ID using VIRTUAL TABLE?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I found  out, that in virtual table Integer Primary Key doesn't work the same way like in normal table. SQLite VIRTUAL TABLE ID assigns "null" value for each row... My question is, how to assign ID for each column using VIRTUAL TABLE (USING fts3)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including table definitions, sample data, and expected and actual results. Given your use of the phrase "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" in reference to a fts virtual table, I'm guessing you didn't read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) well enough, but it'd be nice to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already there and it's named `rowid`.

Here's an example:

```
sqlite> create virtual table search using fts3(text);
sqlite> insert into search values ('london new york');
sqlite> insert into search values ('san francisco');
sqlite> select rowid,* from search;
1|london new york
2|san francisco
```

Same applies for non virtual tables.